# Static Call Graph from binary executables

Tags: static, binary, executable, call-graph

I was wondering if there is any way to statically analyze binaries in linux, and get all potential call flows/control flows.

Essentially a static analysis (with potential aliasing) similar to as is given by LLVM and similar compilers, but from the binary... (i.e. I do not need to recompile etc.)

Thanks